# pthreads synchronization multiple read operations

Tags: multithreading, synchronization, thread-safety, pthreads

Suppose you had a Pthreads program where most of the time you were 
performing  read)only operations on a specific data structure but occasionally 
you were updating the data structure. How could you synchronize accesses 
to that data structure to avoid race conditions and still mostly access the data structure in parallel.
please i need your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[pthreads read-write locks](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_rwlock_destroy.html#) were designed for this use case.

Read-write locks are declared using the `pthread_rwlock_t` type, and initialised either with the static initializer `PTHREAD_RWLOCK_INITIALIZER` or dynamically using `pthread_rwlock_init()`.

The read-only users of your data structure take a read lock with `pthread_rwlock_rdlock()` - an unlimited number of read locks can be held concurrently, so multiple readers can access the data structure simultaneously.  The updating users of your data structure take a write lock with `pthread_rwlock_wrlock()`.  A write lock is exclusive - no other threads can have the read-write locked (either for reading or writing) while a write lock is held.